# How to have parameters in the LaTeX template?

Tags: r-exams

I have a LaTeX template, which I use with `exam2pdf` and where I would like to have the date of the exam as a parameter, whose value should be passed from R. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in two and a half ways:

#### (1) Via the `header` argument

You can set `exams2pdf(..., header = ..., template = ...)` where the content of the `header` is inserted into the `template` by replacing the `%% \exinput{header}` placeholder. Thus, when writing the template you can decide where exactly the header code ends up in the LaTeX code and you can make sure that the appropriate commands/packages are available. The `header` can then be specified in the following ways:

- *LaTeX code:*
  You can include something like `header = "\\command{value}"`. There could be more complex pieces of LaTeX code, involving multiple lines, etc.
- *List of commands and values:*
  Instead of the full LaTeX code it might be more R-like to use a list specification like `header = list(command = "value")`. This is transformed internally to the LaTeX code mentioned above.
- *List of functions:*
  Finally you can also have a specification like `header = list(command = valuefun)` where `valuefun` is a `function(i)` so that you return a different string for the `i`-th random version of the exam.
- *List of all of the above:*
  A list consisting of unnamed character strings, named character string, and named functions can be used as well, combining all three specifications above.

More details are provided in the `vignette("exams", package = "exams")` which explains the design of `exams2pdf()` and how it can be leveraged. It also includes some examples which you can also copy to your working directory via `exams_skeleton(write = "exams2pdf", ...)`. You can look at the `exam.tex` LaTeX template that is shipped with the package to see how you can insert a date and an ID (depending on the `i`-th iteration) into the PDF. For example:

```
exams2pdf("capitals.Rmd", template = "exam.tex",
  header = list(Date = "2022-02-22", ID = function(i) paste("\\#", i)))
```

#### (2) Write a template generator

For the purposes from your question strategy (1) should be sufficient, I guess. However, if you need more control over what is done in the LaTeX template, then my recommendation would be to write a dynamic template generator. This is how `exams2nops()` is set up. It takes a lot of arguments that can be set by the user and then proceeds as follows:

- Depending on the user arguments a corresponding `nops.tex` template is written in a temporary directory.
- Then `exams2pdf(..., template = "/path/to/nops.tex")` is called to use this custom temporary template.
- Some details, especially the counter for the `i`-th ID is still handled through the `header` argument.

Comment: Thanks, Achim! I think I will follow the creation of a template generator approach, as I have several parameters to control.

Comment: As long as you want to control can be set in the LaTeX header of the template, it should not be necessary to write a template generator. Then the question is more about whether you prefer to write R code or LaTeX code. The situation where the template generator is needed is where you want to write LaTeX code in between the exercises (e.g., custom environments, sections, breaks, text, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, Achim! Actually, I want to control other things besides the header. So the best way is to create a template generator.